# Node-Inspector not starting

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-inspector

First, I was having an issue installing node-inspector, I had to revert to installing version `@0.7.5`.. That installed globally on my machine, but now when I try to run `node-inspector` I get the error below. I find it odd that I haven't been able to find much in regards to these two errors.

```
module.js:487
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '_debugger'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:485:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-inspector/lib/debugger.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
```

Comment: did you ever resolve this?

Comment: Same thing. It has been an error for 4 month already according to this thread https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4307

Comment: @Mark no, I wasn't able to. It was a mini node.js project I was writing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This ecosystem moves fast. Now the command is...

```
node inspect yourScript.js
```

https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/debugger.html

Answer (score 11):

I was facing the same issue today. After some googling I found that is deprecated now. Use instead this:

`node --inspect-brk yourScript.js`

Head over to [Official Docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/) for complete reference.

After running the above command, do either of the following two options:

> Option 1: Open chrome://inspect in a Chromium-based browser. Click the Configure button and ensure your target host and port are listed. Then select your Node.js app from the list.

---

> Option 2: Install the Chrome Extension NIM (Node Inspector Manager):
>   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nim-node-inspector-manage/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj

Hope that helps!

Comment: Seems like this answer is now outdated, see @doublejosh 's answer below.